# How to override maven project version in teamcity

Tags: maven, build, continuous-integration, pom.xml, teamcity-9.0

Mine is a maven based java project and for continuous integration I am using Teamcity. For some purpose ( deploy Snapshot and release ) I need to overwrite project version within team city. 
I have tried using maven.project.version and project.version in build step Paramus but no luck.
Currently mentioning it in pom.xml in tag 
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what you want to do.  Do you want to set the version, build, test and if successful update/tag your VCS?  If that is the case, then you probably want to take a look at the `release` plugin and a combination of the goals that it provides.  If you only want to change the version and then build, then the `versions:set` goal will suffice.  If might be helpful if you specify exactly what is your scenario and what do you want to accomplish with your build.

Comment: release plugin on Teamcity you meant. Can you please share any reference link